# arcpy.Raster.save(*.jpg) - format unknown

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.2

The following Python script returns the error on the final line, "RuntimeError: ERROR 010093: Output raster format UNKNOWN is unsupported.":

```
import arcpy
inRaster = arcpy.Raster(r'C:/junk/raster.tif')
outRaster = r'C:/junk/out.jpg'
intermediateRas = inRaster
intermediateRas.save(outRaster)
```

The script runs to completion if outRaster is .tif or ESRI GRID. Why does this not work for .jpg (or .jpeg)? According to the [list of supported raster formats](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/List_of_supported_raster_and_image_data_formats/009t0000000v000000/), JPEG should work.

- ArcGIS 10.2.2

Comment: have you checked the number of bands (3) and the pixel depth (8bit) ?

Comment: I assume you are referring to 'inRaster', since 'outRaster' does not exist. I have tried and failed with 3 band 8 bit, 1 band 8 bit, 3 band >8 bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JPEG is [not supported as an output format](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00p60000000r000000):

> The save method supports all raster formats supported by Spatial
>   Analyst. In the example below the raster save method is used to save
>   data to a file geodatabase raster and to IMAGINE format.

Supported raster 'save' [formats for spatial analyst](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005900000005000000#ESRI_SECTION2_560F396561EB4FC5945C28454EA2A8F0):

> Output raster data formats The supported output raster formats are the
>   following: Esri Grid Geodatabase rasters (This includes File,
>   Personal, and ArcSDE geodatabases.) TIFF (.tif) ERDAS IMAGINE (.img)
>   The location and name you specify for the output raster determines the
>   format in which it is created.

When using `raster.save` your choices are Geodatabase Raster, Esri Grid, GeoTiff and ERDAS imagine format.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you need to be using this method

```
arcpy.RasterToOtherFormat_conversion (Input_Rasters, Output_Workspace, {Raster_Format})
```

You can rename your raster using this method

```
os.rename()
```

More here:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000032000000